# Windows 10 automatically disconects from VPN server

Tags: vpn, windows-10, l2tp

I am connecting to the VPN server with **Windows 10 built-in** provider using **L2TP/IPsec** protocol with **username/password** and a **Pre Shared Key**. Everything is fine except the fact that every 1.5 hours it disconnects automatically. Then I have to go to VPN settings again and press the Connect button to connect to the VPN server.

My friend doesn't experience this problem while connecting to this VPN server from his MacBook. This is a very big issue, that can compromise the privacy of a user. Can someone tell me the reason behind this behavior and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the huge interest in the OP, I will publish the solution myself, that I was told in http://www.windows10forums.com :

1) Go to the **Device Manager**.

2) Expand **network adapters**, select the **adapter(s) you are using** (In my case the Intel wireless and the Realtek PCIe devices), then right click and choose **properties**.

3) Select the **Power Management Tab** from along the top and make sure that the box that says something like **"Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"** is **not checked**.